# Rearranging and reformatting elements of a biblatex-chicago citation

Tags: biblatex-chicago

In my ongoing quest to destroy biblatex-chicago in response to editorial command--definitely going to look into building from a more flexible style for my future projects, if custom in-house publisher styles are going to be common--I need to rearrange two elements of `@incollection` entries.

Based on the MWE given below, the standard output in a footnote for such an entry is:

> F. Lastname, “Longer Article Title,” in *Collected Essays*, ed. I. Editor (City, 1918), 207–225.

and the bibliography is

> Lastname, F. “Longer Article Title.” In *Collected Essays*, edited by I. Editor, 207–225. City, 1918.

There are two elements which I need rearranged (and correspondingly reformatted):
1) the editor needs to go before the title of the collection
2) the pages should go at the end in the bibliography like they do in the footnote.

The target footnote would therefore be:

> F. Lastname, “Longer Article Title,” in I. Editor, ed., *Collected Essays* (City, 1918), 207–225.

and the bibliography would be

> Lastname, F. “Longer Article Title.” In I. Editor, ed., *Collected Essays*. City, 1918, 207–225.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false,shorthandfull]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@incollection{lastname18,
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
title = {Longer Article Title},
shorttitle = {Longer},
pages = {207--225},
booktitle = {Collected Essays},
editor = {Important Editor},
date = {1918},
address = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Text.\autocite{lastname18}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is possible to re-arrange the order of elements in the bibliography (and citations), but what you have in mind likely requires fiddling with the drivers. The bibliography drivers for `biblatex-chicago` are not for the faint-hearted...

Comment: I know it's not a great idea, but at this point I'm not sure what else I can do--it's the final days of a book-length project, so rebuilding my entire citation style (which definitely also relies on certain things that biblatex-chicago does that normal biblatex doesn't) doesn't really seem an option...

Comment: Are these the *only* changes (i.e., only `incollection` changed?) Or should the changes be made for other entry types? If the former, then you could make very specific changes easily enough. The risk of broader changes is that there are unintended consequences with `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: Yes, at this point I'm after a quick fix (though I'm very interested in how it is done).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you state that you are in the final days of a book, my suggestion is to *only* adjust the absolute minimum to get what you want. To do more in a complex style like `biblatex-chicago` risks producing unintended changes elsewhere (as evidenced by the number of edits I've made to this answer).

What will this answer affect:

- *Only* the `incollection` driver.
- *Only* move the `editor` (not `translator`).

To my mind, this will give inconsistent output with similar entry types, but perhaps this is not a problem for you. If needed, you could adjust other types in a similar way.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false,shorthandfull]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{lastname18,
    author = {Lastname, Firstname},
    title = {Longer Article Title},
    shorttitle = {Longer},
    pages = {207--225},
    booktitle = {Collected Essays},
    editor = {Important Editor},
    date = {1918},
    location = {City}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{cmtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}}
  {\ifnameundef{editor}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{cms-in:}%
      \renewbibmacro*{cms-in:}{}%
      \printnames{editor}%
      \editordelim
      \usebibmacro{editstrg}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
   \usebibmacro{cmtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}}
  {\ifnameundef{editor}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{cms-in:}%
      \renewbibmacro*{cms-in:}{}%
      \printnames[default]{editor}%
      \editordelim
      \usebibmacro{editstrg}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
   \usebibmacro{mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{volume+pages}%
   \newunit\newblock}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{publ+loc+year}}
  {\usebibmacro{publ+loc+year}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{volume+pages}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
BibLaTeX output \autocite{lastname18}.

Reference implementation.\footnote{F. Lastname, “Longer Article Title,” in I.
  Editor, ed., \emph{Collected Essays} (City, 1918), 207–225.}

\printbibliography

\noindent Reference implementation:\smallskip

\noindent\hangindent 2em Lastname, F. “Longer Article Title.” In I. Editor, ed., \emph{Collected
Essays}. City, 1918, 207–225.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. The only thing is that for some reason in my real document it gives a long dash instead of the editor's names--like the one used when an author is repeated at the start of a bibliography entry, but here it has no bearing on whether it's an author we've seen before (and it shouldn't be appearing in any case). It's in both the bibliography and the footnotes. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: @Erika, ah yes. missed that one. Try my latest edit.