# Remove "in" from some incollection bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

My style guide has certain peculiarities (seems common on tex.se). For certain, well-known collected works, `incollection` entries are cited *without* the "in" (that refers to the collection) either in the footnote or the bibliography. I was able to get the footnote working with help from david-purton [in this answer to my quesiton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582645/31561)

However, I also need to change the bibliography. The "catch" is that I only need it to change for *some* `incollection` types. That is, for all other `incollection` types I still need the "In " in the bibliography. I looked at these questions and answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437868/31561), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439122/31561), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495261/31561) but they are all global solutions. I could not find an option in either `biblatex-chicago` or `biblatex` on a per-entry basis to edit this. I think perhaps moewe's solutions in the above questions could work if I added an `entrysubtype` and tested for that? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\usepackage[noibid,backend=biber,notes,isbn=false,shorthandfull,shorthandfirst,inheritshorthand=true,citereset=chapter]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
    @mvcollection{mvbigbook,
        editor = {James Editorist},
        title  = {A Larger Collection of Essays},
        shorthand = {AMVCoE},
        volumes = {3},
        options   = {skipbib},
        publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        address = {Oxford},
        year = {1997}}
    @collection{bigbook,
        editor = {John Q. Editormann},
        title  = {A Collection of Essays},
        shorthand = {ACoE},
        options   = {skipbib},
        publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        address = {Oxford},
        year = {1995}}
    @incollection{incol,
        crossref = {bigbook},
        entrysubtype = {tdict},
        options  = {skipbiblist},
        author   = {Steve Authormann},
        title    = {This is an Essay},
        pages    = {1-15}}
    @incollection{incol2,
        crossref = {bigbook},
        entrysubtype = {tdict},
        options  = {skipbiblist},
        author   = {John Essaymann},
        title    = {An Essay on Collections},
        pages    = {16-30}}
    @incollection{incol3,
        crossref = {mvbigbook},
        entrysubtype = {tdict},
        options  = {skipbiblist},
        author   = {Jack Essayist},
        title    = {An Essay on Multi Volume Collections},
        pages    = {2:31-40}}
    @incollection{incol4,
        crossref = {mvbigbook},
        entrysubtype = {tdict},
        options  = {skipbiblist},
        author   = {Bob Contraryist},
        title    = {I do not like Multi Volume Collections},
        pages    = {3:100-104}}
    \end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfEmptyF \tl_if_blank:nF
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfEmptyTF \tl_if_blank:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {\ifentrysubtype{tdict}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
      {\printtext{%
         \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
    {\printtext{%
       \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\makeatletter
\def\paul@blx@trackentry@global#1{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\sbl@blx@tempa}{#1}%
     \xifinlistcs{\sbl@blx@tempa}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
       {}
       {\listcsxadd{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{\sbl@blx@tempa}}}
    {}}
\let\paul@blx@trackentry\paul@blx@trackentry@global

\NewDocumentCommand{\fcd}{o o m}{%
  \footnote{%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\IfNoValueF{#2}{#1 }}%
    \blx@imc@ifentryseen{#3}
      {\citeauthor{#3}, \citetitle{#3}, }
      {\citename{#3}[default]{labelname}, \citetitle{#3},
       \paul@blx@trackentry{#3}}%
    \citefield{#3}{shorthand}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{, #1}{\IfEmptyTF{#2}{, \citefield{#3}{pages}}{, #2}}.}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\cd}{o o m}{%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{\IfNoValueF{#2}{#1 }}%
  \blx@imc@ifentryseen{#3}
    {\citeauthor{#3}, \citetitle{#3}, }
    {\citename{#3}[default]{labelname}, \citetitle{#3},
     \paul@blx@trackentry{#3}}%
  \citefield{#3}{shorthand}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{, #1}{\IfEmptyTF{#2}{, \citefield{#3}{pages}}{, #2}}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\fcmvd}{o o m}{%
  \footnote{%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\IfNoValueF{#2}{#1 }}%
    \blx@imc@ifentryseen{#3}
      {\citeauthor{#3}, \citetitle{#3}, }
      {\citename{#3}[default]{labelname}, \citetitle{#3},
       \paul@blx@trackentry{#3}}%
    \citefield{#3}{shorthand}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{ #1}{\IfEmptyTF{#2}{ \citefield{#3}{pages}}{ #2}}.}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmvd}{o o m}{%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{\IfNoValueF{#2}{#1 }}%
  \blx@imc@ifentryseen{#3}
    {\citeauthor{#3}, \citetitle{#3}, }
    {\citename{#3}[default]{labelname}, \citetitle{#3},
     \paul@blx@trackentry{#3}}%
  \citefield{#3}{shorthand}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{ #1}{\IfEmptyTF{#2}{ \citefield{#3}{pages}}{ #2}}}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\printbiblist{shorthand}
\null\vfill
I need to reference this in a footnote.\fcd[See][]{incol} But this is
another footnote.\fcd[See][18]{incol2} I need the second footnote
twice.\fcd[20]{incol2} But I have a different argument.%
\footnote{%<<<
This is in contrast to what is seen in \cd[28]{incol2}.
} %>>>

This is a new reference collection.\fcmvd[See][]{incol3} But this is another
reference to it with pages.\fcmvd[See][3:101]{incol4} I should cite the first
one again.\fcmvd[2:35]{incol3} But perhaps it is wrong.%
\footnote{%<<<
This guy reall does not like essays, \cmvd[see][3:104]{incol4}.
} %>>>
\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get for footnotes and the bibliography:

[image: footnotes]
[image: bib]

The footnotes are all correct, but the bibliography is not. The "In " (including space delimeter) need to be removed.

As you can see, another problem I had was that for multivolume entries, there should be no comma between the mvcollection and the pages (which include the volume). I did this in the footnote in a "hacky" way by making a multivolume cite command. But I also need to remove the comma in the bibliography for `incollection` types where the parent is an `mvcollection`. Perhaps the solution that removes the "In " in the bibliography can be easily extended to also remove the comma when the parent is an `mvcollection`? And could it work for the footnotes as well?

**UPDATE:**
I edited the MWE above with my best guess from moewe's solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437842/how-do-i-change-format-of-biblatex-bibliography-entries/437868#437868). However it doesn't do anything. I think that there is no `ifentrysubtype` in `biblatex`. But also, renewing that bibmacro doesn't do anything. I placed all sort of text and nothing in my bib changed. So it must not be using that macro. However, I couldn't find any other bibmacro in `biblatex.def` that did anything with `in`.

Comment: There are 12 instances of `\bibstring{in}` in `chicago-notes.cbx`. You would have to check for each of those calls whether or not it could become relevant for your "in"s and if so, guard it with the `\ifentrysubtype{tdict}{<true>}{<false>}` test. `biblatex-chicago` is really not intended for large-scale modification: The CMoS requirements are so complex that the `biblatex` code is extremely complex as well. So even 'small' changes can easily take several hundred lines of code.

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` reimplements many bibmacros and drivers, so the definitions you find in `biblatex.def` might not be relevant for `biblatex-chicago` or might have been overwritten with different definitions. Answers on this site that apply to the standard styles may not apply one-to-one to `biblatex-chicago`. In this case (i.e. `\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}`) you will want to search for instances of "in" in `chicago-notes.bbx` and `chicago-notes.cbx`.

Comment: @moewe thanks! I figured `biblatex-chicago` overwrote it, but didn't think about 12 different versions! Thanks for the help, I'll look into it!